# Adjusting colorbar legend limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, colorbar

I have the following python code to plot a surface contour plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import pandas as pd

dx = {'1': 1, '2': -1, '3': -1, '4': 1, '5': 0}
x = pd.Series(data=dx, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

dy = {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': -1, '4': -1, '5': 0}
y = pd.Series(data=dy, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

dT = {'1': 10, '2': 20, '3': 30, '4': 40, '5': 50}
T = pd.Series(data=dT, index=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.tricontourf(x, y, T, cmap=cm.turbo)
plt.colorbar(extend='both')
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

But, I want the colorbar to be between 0 to 100.

So, I added the following

```
plt.clim(0,100)
```

Doing so, gives me the following plot:

[image]

How do I get to change the colorbar legend also to 0-100?

@JohanC - I tried that. It does not quite work. It changes the granularity on the plot too, which I do not want. See below:

[image]

So, I tried this:

```
plt.tricontourf(x, y, T, cmap=cm.turbo,levels=np.arange(0,101,5))
```

and I get this (where it does not show 100 on the top, even though it is actually present):

[image]

Could you please help, how I can force the end point labels to be explicitly printed? Thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe `plt.tricontourf(..., levels=np.arange(10,101,10))` does what you want?

Comment: `... and I get this (where it does not show 100 on the top ...` The next label text is 105, skipping 100 that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and add `ticks` parameter:

```
plt.colorbar(extend='both', ticks=np.arange(0,101,10))
```

Output:

[image]